# After Upgrading, XCode gives "The Package Does Not Contain an Info.plist" error when Archiving

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an iOS 7 app in the app store which has many in-app purchases. The in-app purchases are simply new .json data structures that I have hosted with Apple. The IAPs used to submit perfectly, but I just upgraded to XCode 6.1 when I upgraded my machine from Mountain Lion to Yosemite. Now whenever I archive a new IAP package or rearchive an old one that submitted properly last week, I get:

"Unable to validate your application. The package does not contain an Info.plist".

When I click on my target (in the Navigator pane), Build Settings | Packaging shows:

- **Info.plist File** as "north_carolina.pittsburgh/ContentInfo.plist". (Debug and Release subheadings show the same information).
- **Product Name** is "north_carolina.pittsburgh".

The ContentInfo.plist file is in the Supporting Files folder of my target (in the Navigator pane). In it I have keys for

- ContentVersion (value set to 2.0)
- IAPProductIdentifier
- Bundle versions string, short (value set to 2.0)

Finally, in the Products folder of the Navigator, I have north_carolina.pittsburgh next to the red target icon, and the words are in red.

How can I get this archive to validate properly?

Comment: Make sure that your plist file exists in your project navigator, and that it's not highlighted in red. (in case it has been removed or renamed on disc, for whatever reason)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have a "ContentInfo.plist" file. It's contents are outlined in the second bullet list. Is there a different .plist file that needs to be in the package?

Answer (score 8):

The error message is incorrect. What it's really erroring out on is that your "version" and "bundle" number strings probably aren't both set. Make sure you specify both in the Identity section.
[image]

Comment: Downvoted because version/build number does not apply to In App Purchase projects in Xcode which is what the OP is struggling with.

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have more upvote this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be XCode 6.1 bug. However you can actually ignore the error and proceed to export as an installer package (.pkg file will be created). Use this .pkg in the Application Loader.

Comment: Application Loader will tell you that it is invalid because it contains an executable.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, exporting does not work as Application Loader gives the same error. I have also tried recreating the IAP projects from scratch in Xcode 6.1 and it gives the same error. I've logged the error with Apple (19095529) and it is duplicate of 18893033 so they must know about the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with the Xcode Archiver but I was able to submit using the Application Loader. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Open Application Loader and select **New In-App Purchase** and click the **Choose** button
2. A new pop-up opens with your app list from iTunes Connect. Click on the app for which you're adding the in-app purchase, and then click the **Manage** button.
3. You should see the list of in-app purchases you've created for your app. Select the in-app purchase you're uploading. Then click the **Hosted Content** tab at the bottom of the pop-up window.
4. The window should update with a new section that says **Hosted Content Package**. Click the **Choose...** button and find the .pkg file you exported from the Archiver. Then click the **Next** button.
5. You should get the message  *Validation completed. Your package has validated correctly.* Click **Deliver** and you should see the message *Uploaded package to the iTunes Store*.

If you go to your in-app purchase in iTunes Connect you should see the package you just uploaded under the **Hosting Content With Apple section**. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set "Bundle OS Type code" as "APPL" it solved my problem , but you have to ensure that its in your project directory , include short and version string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out to be a problem with spaces in the .app name. Make sure the product name does not have any

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it appears that the organizer does not provides the information if there is an error.

The best is to:
- export the file as an ipa
- use application loader

Then you will have a DETAILLED explanation about the issue

In my case, the error was that the architecture was Arm7 (on an old project) while the request now is to be 'standard (arm7/arm8/arm64) as well a CFBundlePackageType entry.