# Cannot Submit App to the App Store: Info.plist does not exist

Tags: ios, cordova, testflight

I have used Cordova to create an iOS app. I can successfully test my app on the iOS simulator and I can export the app as well. However, when I try and "submit" the app, I get an error that "Archive Submssion failed due to the issues below: Unable to validate your application. The package does not contain an Info.plist". 
However, my app does contain an Appname-Info.plist. Any insight into this issue and a fix would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oftentimes, the info.plist is named AppName-Info.plist -- that might help (make sure you capitalize it the same way as the name of the project file)?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Thanks for the input. Sorry about the type- my app does contain an <Appname>-Info.plist. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated (the app name is capitalized).

Answer (score 1):

You have to not only have one, but your project file has to point to it as well.  Try opening the project file in Xcode, selecting the target, then the "Build Settings" tab.  From there, look for a section called "Packaging" and for a key called "Info.plist File".  In there, you should see the relative path to the plist file in your project.  Make sure it is specifically set for the Release profile, though it should probably be the same for all profiles unless you're doing something special.

I haven't used Cordova, so I'm not really sure if it tends to mess this up, but this is my best guess for why you'd get an error about a missing file when you're certain it's there in the package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the "Info.plist File" key, the relative path specified is the same as the path for the "Release" profile. The path is " AppNameFolder/AppName-Info.plist " where AppNameFolder is within the .../platforms/ios . Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's unfortunately my best guess.  I searched around and saw a few other people mentioning a similar issue though.  Do any of the solutions here help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630970/after-upgrading-xcode-gives-the-package-does-not-contain-an-info-plist-error

Also, I assume you're doing an 'App Store' submission via XCode when this happens - right?