# Unable to validate : Could not find a CFBundlePackageType

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to upload my iOS `app archive` to iTunes Connect using `Xcode`, but when I click "Upload to App Store" I get the error:

> "Could not find a CFBundlePackageType within the info.plist; or the package is missing an Info.plist"

in my `info.plist` i have:

```
-Bundle OS Type code : APPL
-Bundle creator OS Type code : APPL
```

what's wrong in that configuration ? My application is create for IPad and IPhone

Comment: checkout this answers [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630970/after-upgrading-xcode-gives-the-package-does-not-contain-an-info-plist-error) it may help you

Comment: His problem is that he can not find the file info.plist but mine is here ... well I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a certificate that was not good, I don't know why, but Xcode did not generate the correct error.